# Sorting javascript array by first key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am working on a small project and have ran into a dilemma that may be easy for some people to solve. I am need to sort an array that contains a float value of a distance from point A to point B and a string of an Address. If I have the array without a string in it the array will sort fine using the `array.sort(function(a,b){return a-b})` but when I add the string value it does not sort correctly.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var data = <?php echo json_encode($corodinates); ?>;
        var nearest = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < 420; i++)
        {
            var markers = [(data.Latitude[i]), (data.Longitude[i])];
            var userLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(42.4999923706, -96.4003067017);
            var dealerLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0], markers[1]);
            var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(userLocation, dealerLocation);
                nearest[i] = [(distance/1609.344), (data.Address[i])];
        }       

        nearest.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
    </script>
```

This is what my array looks like:

```
0: 482.5813729353341
1: "10940 S Parker Road #723"
```

I need it to sort by the float value in the 0 key.

Comment: `function(a,b){return a[0]-b[0]}`? Or is there something I can't see?

Comment: I commented on jfriend00's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to reach into the array that is in the array element to get the distance values and use those in the sort callback:

```
nearest.sort(function(a,b){return a[0]-b[0]});
```

Comment: This does not sort it numerically ascending. It will list my array by the first integer I have an 88.xxxxx in there and it is listed in with the 800.xxxx

Comment: @Yamaha32088 I don't understand.... what is `a[0]` in your case if not the value you want to sort by?

Comment: *"I have an 88.xxxxx in there and it is listed in with the 800.xxxx "* What does that even mean?

Comment: It is the value I want to sort by the lowest value in the array is 88.xxxxx but with the way your code is sorting the array is that it lists 1004.xxxxx first and the lowest value 88.xxxxx is listed with the values that in 800.xxxxx

Comment: @Yamaha32088 - your code about shows the first array value to be a floating point number `distance/1609.344`.  If that's the case, then you should be able to just subtract two numbers in order to sort by that value.  If you're getting the opposite order you want, then just reverse the order like `b[0]-a[0]`.

Comment: @FelixKling I guess it means it's time to closevote as unclear :-)

Comment: 88 is smaller than 1000 but 1000 is listed first in the sorted array

Comment: @Yamaha32088 yet we have no idea why. Can you provide a test case (say, with fake data) in http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @Yamaha32088 - please show us some actual data that you want sorted.  The code we've given you sorts numbers numerically and you can determine whether you want ascending or descending order by how you order the subtraction.

Comment: I found the issue I had a typo sorry I had `nearest.sort(function(a,b){return a[0]-b}[0]);` instead of `nearest.sort(function(a,b){return a[0]-b[0]});` notice the key was placed outside the curly brackets

Comment: @Yamaha32088: If you tell the truth and the first element of the nested arrays is a number, then this solution will work: http://jsfiddle.net/FGaLb/. If it doesn't for you, your data is different.

Answer (score 1):

```
nearest.sort(function(a,b){return a[0]-b[0]});
```

do like this